# Login Control in ASP.net using XML

Tags: asp.net, xml

I've been searching for ages looking for some help on this but can't find anything i can understand.

All I want to do is bind an XML file to a login control in ASP.net. I can get them all working with a grid view, but I don't understand how to get it to work with a login control.

Does anyone know?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<employee>
<User>
<username>Admin</username>
<password>Password</password>
 </User>
<employee/>
```

is my XML file

and my Login control is

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F6F3" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" 
    BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
    Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333" Height="307px" 
    onauthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" Width="689px">
    <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
    <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" 
        BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" 
        ForeColor="White" />
</asp:Login>
```

What I want to do is connect them together so I can login to my site. Then if the login is successful it will redirect to a page

Comment: Exactly what do you need to bind? From what piece of XML (show an example) to which properties of the control?

Comment: please mark the answer as correct if help you, to help others finding an answer to same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Your xml has an error on closing employee, should be:

```
</employee>
```

On your code behind page_load, loginControl_load or logincontrol_init method try:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/path/to/file.xml"));
        System.Xml.XmlNode usernameNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/employee/User/username");
        string username = usernameNode.InnerText;
        System.Xml.XmlNode passwordNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/employee/User/password");
        string password = passwordNode.InnerText;
        Login1.UserName = username;
        ((TextBox)Login1.FindControl("Password")).Attributes.Add("Value", password);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how would you know what his problem is - he hasn't actually described it.

Comment: Thanks, In the end I couldn't get it working so I've had to use the adminster website tool and done it like that.